# how to pass data to call/cc?

Tags: scheme, continuations

I try to implement function that takes list of atoms and returns only sub part of given list. Sub part is everything after particular token. I try to use `call-with-current-continuation` for that purpose.

Here is my approach:

```
(define rest 
  (lambda (a lat)
    (call-with-current-continuation 
      (lambda (res)
        (letrec ((r (lambda (l)
                      (cond 
                        ((null? l) ())
                        ((eq? (car l) a) (res (cdr l)))
                        (else (r (cdr l)))))))
        (r lat))))))
```

as you can see I try to pass data to continuation 
`((eq? (car l) a) (res (cdr l)))` but I always get back `()` using this approach. But if I hard-coded values like this `((eq? (car l) a) (apple tea)` it works fine.

I am really stuck and I need help.

**EDIT**: I've found solution instead of `(res (cdr l))` I have to pass `(res (r (cdr l)))`

Also real mistake was not with how I call `continuation`, but with `(else (r (cdr l)))))))`  I should write as:

```
(else (cons (car l)
      (r (cdr l))))))))
```

Comment: Works fine for me in Racket: `(rest 'c '(a b c d))` yields `'(d)`. What implementation are you using?

Comment: Same for Guile, works fine. I might mention that I replaced `()` by `'()` in your code but I don't think this matters because your implementation would give a compile error if it did.

Comment: Can you add an example that doesn't work? Chances are that you don't work with symbols so `eq?` might be inappropriate.

Comment: @uselpa  I've found a solution `(res (r (cdr l))))` for some reasons in order for this to work I have to pass function which will be executed.

Comment: Doesn't make sense to me. Please add an example of what doesn't work.

Comment: @uselpa hm, strange I try to rerun example that didn't work for me and now it's working perfectly fine. An, I've found mistake in my code, in the original code I wrote `(else (r (cdr l)))))))` but instead I should do this  `(else (cons (car l)
                                    (r (cdr l))))))))`

Comment: Doesn't make sense either, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine in MIT-Scheme 9.2:

```
MIT/GNU Scheme running under OS X
Type `^C' (control-C) followed by `H' to obtain information about interrupts.

Copyright (C) 2014 Massachusetts Institute of Technology
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions. There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR
PURPOSE.

Image saved on Wednesday February 24, 2016 at 8:07:52 PM
  Release 9.2 || Microcode 15.3 || Runtime 15.7 || SF 4.41 || LIAR/C 4.118 || Edwin 3.116

1 ]=> (define rest
  (lambda (a lat)
    (call-with-current-continuation
      (lambda (res)
        (letrec ((r (lambda (l)
                      (cond
                        ((null? l) ())
                        ((eq? (car l) a) (res (cdr l)))
                        (else (r (cdr l)))))))
        (r lat))))))

;Value: rest

1 ]=> (rest 'c '(a b c d))

;Value 2: (d)

1 ]=> (rest 'c '(a b c d e))

;Value 3: (d e)

1 ]=> (rest 'c ())

;Value: ()
```

My best guess is that you're working with objects where `eq?` is the inappropriate comparison procedure.

FWIW, here's a shorter implementation:

```
(define (rest a lat)
  (call-with-current-continuation
   (lambda (res)
     (let r ((l lat))
       (if (null? l)
           '()
           ((if (eq? (car l) a) res r) (cdr l)))))))
```

Comment: the `cond` version is much clearer though. also, [`res` is a no-op](http://ideone.com/2saxXp), as `r` is tail recursive, isn't it?

Comment: What do you mean by "res is a no-op"? `res` is the continuation.

Comment: In `((if (eq? (car l) a) res r) (cdr l)))))))`, either `res` or `r` are called with `(cdr l)` as the argument, depending on whether `(car l)` is equal to `a` or not.

Comment: what I meant was, `r` is tail recursive, so its termination clause returns the value anyway; there's no jump. calling the exit continuation at that point does nothing - we're already exiting. the code works without it just as well, as was demonstrated by [the ideone link](http://ideone.com/2saxXp) in my comment. :) (and I was referring to the cond version).

Comment: @WillNess Yes that's true.